# How to manipulate information from a GET response

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I'm new to java / rest / jersey, so please bear with me.

Problem: I want to use a GET method to retrieve some information I have previously POSTed. My only confusion is...where is the information after I call the GET?

Here is my post (you can ignore it as I know this part works):

```
@POST @Path("/tools")
public Response createTool(JsonNode tool) throws URISyntaxException {

    //use custom validator to de-couple implementation from validation 
    ToolValidator validator = new ToolValidator(tool);

    if(validator.isNotNull() == false) {
        System.out.println("in not null");
        return Response.status(400).entity("Please add tool details").build();
    } 

    if (validator.hasValidType() == false) {
        System.out.println("in valid timestamp");
        return Response.status(400).entity("Please provide a valid tool type").build();
    }

    if(validator.haveValidValues() == false ) {
        System.out.println("in valid values");
        return Response.status(400).entity("Please provide a tools list with valid numerical values").build();
    }

    String type= tool.get("type").asText();

    return Response.status(201).entity(tool).build().created(new URI("/tools/"+type)).build();

}
```

It definitely posts a tool correctly (I've tested it and seen it, I believe this works but it might not).

Now what I want to do is get the json, see if adheres to some requirements, and return an answer.  Basically, irrelevant of the POST code above, for any url that returns some json when you navigate to it, I want to be able to grab that json and do something with it.

```
@GET @Path("/tools/{type}")
public Response getToolInfo(@PathParam("type") String type) {
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

My only question here is..."where" is the information to manipulate?? I feel like I'm asking an extremely fundamental, basic question for REST / Jersey, so I apologize if this is like the ABCs here.

Basically, I use my POST method to POST a tool with some specific json.  I can navigate to that page and see the json object.  Now I want to use a GET method to analyze the json but...I have no idea how / where this information is stored when I decide to use a GET method.

Does the @get annotation automatically store the information returned from the specified path somewhere? Does anything?

Comment: when you do a POST you have to store the information somewhere.  
and then have GET use that data store to retrieve the information. Generally Restful services use a database (noSQL, SQL... to store the information).  For test purposes you can just store it in memory (a separate static class would work for this)

Comment: Apologies, it was my mistake to post the POST code.  What I meant by the question was, let's say a certain url returns json when you navigate to it (think of many publicly exposed apis). How would I, with a GET method, get that json to manipulate it?

Comment: Usually, we don't use request body in GET method. Please refer to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp . For GET method, you just get query parameter & path parameter as you do. You don't need handle JSON comes from GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you pasted it doesn't look like anything is stored. In your `@POST` it looks like you pass `JsonNode tool`, from that you create an object of type `ToolValidator` which you use to do some sort of validation. From your `JsonNode tool` you retrieve a field called "type".

At last you create a response instance with the parameter you already passed and you change the Uri to "/tools/" and the String value of whatever is in the variable "type".

So it doesn't look like you are doing any database access to store the `JsonNode` passed as parameter.

> It definitely posts a tool correctly (I've tested it and seen it).

It posts the tool because of this `Response.status(201).entity(tool).build()`
You are just simply telling it to set the response entity in the builder. Whereas `build()` a response instance.

For testing purposes only create a global variable, in your class, of type JsonNode and copy the passed parameter (`JsonNode tool`), in your POST method, to your global variable. Then you can retrieve it in your GET method. Don't forget to create getter and setter for your global variable.

In a real life scenario though you would be storing things in your database. If it's just for some prototype then a global variable should be enough

---

Here is a tiny example of what I mean:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private JsonNode copiedTool;

    @POST @Path("/tools")
    public Response createTool(JsonNode tool) throws URISyntaxException {

        setCopiedTool(tool);

        String type= tool.get("type").asText();

        return Response.status(201).entity(getCopiedTool()).build().created(new URI("/tools/"+type)).build();
    }

    @GET @Path("/tools/{type}")
    public Response getToolInfo(@PathParam("type") String type) {

        if(getCopiedTool().get("type").equals(type)) {
            return Response.ok(getCopiedTool()).build();
        }
        return Response.status(204).build();
    }


    public JsonNode getCopiedTool() {
        return copiedTool;
    }

    public void setCopiedTool(JsonNode copiedTool) {
        this.copiedTool = copiedTool;
    }
}
```

Comment: Apologies, it was my mistake to post the POST code.  I might be wrong with what I believe is posted. What I meant by the question was, let's say a certain url returns json when you navigate to it (think of many publicly exposed apis). How would I, with a GET method, get that json to manipulate it?

Comment: I updated my answer so you can understand how the storage and retrieval should work